# Get different behavior using `window.open()` and `window.loaction` in Word add-ins

Tags: office-js

I want open a url with browser in my word add-in, see the code:

```
window.open(url);
```

works fine in windows OS.

But it shows nothing in iMac(10.12.2, word 2016) just open a blank dialog. However, this code works fine in my Macbook pro 13'(10.13.2, word 2016)

I read a document got from Microsoft, said that if I use `window.location = url` the url must in `<AppDomains>`.

But, on that iMac, even if the url not in `<AppDomains>` the page shows in add-in.

Now, I want to know, how to open a url with browser in add-ins, which function should be used?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify: Have you tried putting the URL in AppDomains?

Comment: Yeah, I found that `window.location` didn't work in iMac whether the URL in AppDomains or not. However `window.location.href` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `<a />` tags/links, you should use `target="_blank"`. This will always open the URL in an external window.

When you need to open a new window via JavaScript, you should use Office's [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). The Dialog API was designed to smooth out all of the subtle differences in windowing behavior between the various platforms and browsers Office might be running on.

With regards to `<AppDomains>`, the intended behavior is that domains listed in this node will open within the add-in's browser session. This ensures the Dialog API can communicate between the parent (add-in) and child (new window). If the URL isn't included in `<AppDomains>` it will open using the user's default browser.

Comment: Thanks for that. `window.location.href = URL` works fine.